# "Access the internet on my phone" or "access the internet from my phone"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which preposition I use in the following sentence before *phone*: *on* or *from*?

> If I can't access the internet **on**/**from** my phone, what would you suggest I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On** and **from** both sound OK to me. (A web search for "access the internet on/from my phone" gives plenty of hits either way.)

**From** gives a slight impression that the phone's location is being contrasted with the remote location of the internet. Your phone is trying to "reach" the internet.

**On** works because you are *on your phone* when using it.

**With** would also work.

Answer (score 0):

NGrams produces only one result for ["internet * my phone"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20internet%20%2A%20my%20phone&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20internet%20on%20my%20phone%3B%2Cc0) and that is **on** my phone